# Android Emulator - Can't connect to development server - React Native

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, react-native

I am react-native v.60.5.  My app was running.  Then it just wasn't it seems.  No changes I think.  I was playing with the manifest.xml in app main trying to get an anchor for my cert so I could do some other things on my network but I have removed anything I was trying with that.  These emulators just seem really janky to me.  I can't seem to get past this error.

[image: Initial Error]

Then when I 'RR' it says my development server is not available.

[image: Subsequent Error]

I have ensured the package server is running.  The emulator is connected to my machine (haven't changed it's network settings) an USB debugging is enabled, I doubled checked.  Adb shows my device is connected.  Airplane mode is disabled.  I've tried both localhost:5678 and 10.0.1.1.:5678.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml in app/src/main

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.reactregionlocator">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get my emulator running again?

Comment: Did you try `react-native start` ?

Comment: Yes.  I actually just created a new project using `react-native init MyNewProject` last night, copied in my code, created a new emulator.   Everything is working again.  Idk, this stuff is so janky and Im new too it so who knows at this point.  I will not mess with a AndroidManifest anytime in the near future that is for sure.